# sliding drawer options android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation

I have a project where the designs require a sliding drawer that comes from the bottom and has essentially three states.

1. fully collapsed (just the handle at the bottom
2. half mast (drawer opens from bottom but only halfway up the screen
3. full mast (drawer opens from bottom and takes up the whole screen minus a top margin of lets say 80dp

I am developing for android 4.0 and higher and obviously sliding drawer is deprecated.  But the Navigation drawer only supports left and right (which i already have in use)

So i am wondering if anyone knows a tutorial or even a custom component someone has written that meets the above functionality requirements

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you probably have to create something yourself, but since you're developing for api lvl 14, check out `ObjectAnimator`. It allows you to move Views around and still use them (by that I mean that it's the original view that has been moved and not a copy of it)
This will probably be the easiest way.

FYI, using the Navigation Drawer, you can't open the drawer halfway, or you should programmatically invoke touch events...

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you are looking for.**

I have found this library best so far for sliding up menus in Android.

**https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel**

[image]

You can specify what screen area slide up menu or view will use.

**Accept & vote up my answer if it is what you are looking for.**

Comment: How to specify? which attributes need to set the value?